# Crontab does not work

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, cron, cron-task

This is my crontab file using `sudo crontab -e` in Ubuntu. The first 2 lines do not work. But all the rest work smoothly. I cannot understand why? What can be the problem? Thanks

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/bak/autopost/index.php
* * * * * php /var/www/html/bak/autopost/autosubmitimage.php
30 21 * * * php /var/www/html/bak/cron-update-aff-posts.php
30 23 * * * php /var/www/html/bak/cron-update-aff-posts.php
30 01 * * * php /var/www/html/bak/cron-update-aff-posts.php
30 06 * * * php /var/www/html/bak/cron-update-aff-posts.php
30 08 * * * php /var/www/html/bak/cron-update-aff-posts.php
30 10 * * * php /var/www/html/bak/cron-update-aff-posts.php
30 12 * * * php /var/www/html/bak/cron-update-aff-posts.php
31 01 * * * php /var/www/html/affiliates/bak/cron_post_to_wall.php
31 03 * * * php /var/www/html/affiliates/bak/cron_post_to_wall.php
31 05 * * * php /var/www/html/affiliates/bak/cron_post_to_wall.php
31 10 * * * php /var/www/html/affiliates/bak/cron_post_to_wall.php
31 12 * * * php /var/www/html/affiliates/bak/cron_post_to_wall.php
31 14 * * * php /var/www/html/affiliates/bak/cron_post_to_wall.php
31 16 * * * php /var/www/html/affiliates/bak/cron_post_to_wall.php
*  *  * * * php /var/www/html/images/update.php
```

Comment: Do you want to call a page every second?

Comment: @VladutZzZ the command is for every minute. You cant run crontab every second